# need to understand the difference in delay for rising and falling reference

Tags: transistors, delay

I am rigging up a circuit which needs to generate two signals.

One output signal(R_B) is same as input and the other signal(R_A) is supposed to have a short delay of 5 to 10 ms compared to the input.

The figure below has the waveform and the circuit.
[image]

[image]
Question:
Why is the delay is different when the input rises and the input falls?
any hints towards matching the delay is appreciated.

Edit: after adding a resistor to the base pin and a little balancing, able to achieve 10 ms.:

[image]
[image]

Comment: your hint is Vbe and Miller cap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ground to 3.3v swing the voltage across C1 changes from zero to about 0.7 volts where the transistor is turned on.  That takes time.  But for the 3.3v to ground swing, the voltage across C1 drops below 0.7 volts almost immediately on the way down to zero volts.  So the transistor turns off almost immediately.

Redesign the circuit such that the capacitor can charge beyond the Vbe 0.7 limit by adding a resistor in front of the base.  Allow the capacitor to charge just to about 1.4 volts.  That way it should take about as long for the capacitor to discharge from 1.4 to 0.7 volts on its way to zero volts as it does to charge from zero to 0.7 volts on its way to 1.4 volts.

Comment: +1 I have updated the question with your working solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All output circuits which rely on a resistor to take the output to 'high' have such a a behavior. Once the transistor is conducting, it takes time for the transistor to come out of the conduction phase (this is called charge storage, in the base). At the other situation (output from high to low), the transistor is much faster to start conducting.

TTL ([Transistor Transistor Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic)) improved on this, by putting in a second transistor instead of the resistor, in a circuit called 'Totem-pole output'.
(Similar is used in CMOS circuits)

So how to make the circuit faster?

- Reduce the base current to reduce the storage effect
- Use an active circuit at the output (like TTL)

Comment: Glad this helped you! If this was your solution please don't forget to mark the answer, so others can find it more easily!